# Change dataframe column names while referencing the dataframe using a string holding its name

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to change the column names of a dataframe in  `R`, while using a string holding the dataframe name to reference it. However, my attempt fails:

```
> dataframe <- data.frame(c(1,2), c(3,4))
> dfname <- "dataframe"
> colnames(get(dfname))
[1] "c.1..2." "c.3..4."
> colnames(get(dfname)) <- c("col1", "col2")
Error in colnames(get(dfname)) <- c("col1", "col2"):
  could not find function "get<-"
```

How can I get this example to work and change the column names of `dataframe` while using only `dfname`?

Comment: Is this an option: `dataframe <- "colnames<-"(get(dfname), c("col1", "col2"))` ?

Comment: Not quite, but close enough! 
`assign(dfname, "colnames<-"(get(dfname),c("col1","col2")))` does what I want. Thanks! I just don't understand the syntax behind this... Mind hinting me which keyword to look for when googling it?

Comment: ah I answered before seeing this solution, I suggest you use `setNames` instead : `assign(dfname, setNames(get(dfname),c("col1","col2")))`. I don't know either what keyword corresponds to `*<-` functions but to understand them you have to realise that when you call `colnames(x) <- y` the parser transforms it into  something similar to `x <- 'colnames<-'(x,y)`, you can access this function directly as markus did here, though in this case it's better to use `setNames` which is designed just for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
eval(substitute(x <- setNames(x,c("col1", "col2")),list(x=as.name(dfname))))
dataframe
#   col1 col2
# 1    1    3
# 2    2    4
```